# Ошибка при развертывании проекта на Symfony 2.8

Tags: php, symfony2, redis

у меня linux mint, при попытке запустить проект выдает ошибку:   **This page isn’t working**.

Выполнив команду:  `php app/check.php` пишет что все ОК и система готова к запуску (Your system is ready to run Symfony projects)

При выполнения команды очистки кеша (или же любой другой команды через console):

```
php app/console cache:clear --env=prod
```

или

```
 php app/console cache:clear -e prod
```

Вылазит ошибка:

```
 [RuntimeException]                                            
 The factory can only instantiate \Redis classes: Redis asked
```

Конфиг langu2.loc.conf:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName domain.tld
    ServerAlias langu2.loc

    DocumentRoot /var/www/langu2.loc/web
    <Directory /var/www/langu2.loc/web>
        AllowOverride None
        Order Allow,Deny
        Allow from All
    Require all granted

        <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
            Options -MultiViews
            RewriteEngine On
            RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
            RewriteRule ^(.*)$ app.php [QSA,L]
        RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
        </IfModule>
    </Directory>

    # uncomment the following lines if you install assets as symlinks
    # or run into problems when compiling LESS/Sass/CoffeeScript assets
    # <Directory /var/www/langu2.loc>
    #     Options FollowSymlinks
    # </Directory>

    # optionally disable the RewriteEngine for the asset directories
    # which will allow apache to simply reply with a 404 when files are
    # not found instead of passing the request into the full symfony stack
    <Directory /var/www/langu2.loc/web/bundles>
        <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
            RewriteEngine Off
        </IfModule>
    </Directory>
    ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/langu2_error.log
    CustomLog /var/log/apache2/langu2_access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

parameters.yml:

```
parameters:
database_host: 127.0.0.1
database_port: 3306
database_name: langu
database_user: root
database_password: 123456
admin_database_host: 127.0.0.1
admin_database_port: 3306
admin_database_name: langu
admin_database_user: root
admin_database_password: 123456
mailer_transport: smtp
mailer_host: 127.0.0.1
mailer_user: null
mailer_password: null
mailer_override_address: {  }
secret: ThisTokenIsNotSoSecretChangeIt
google_client_id: null
google_client_secret: null
google_app_name: null
google_app_scopes: null
tokbox_api_key: null
tokbox_api_secret: null
tokbox_session_routed_mode: false
mangopay_client_id: null
mangopay_client_password: null
mangopay_base_url: null
mangopay_debug_mode: true
fixer_key: d7a2c4d1ad4672aafe12a35ef07426e3
langu_exchange_rate_fee: !!float 0
langu_wallets:
    EUR:
        wallet: 17988934
        user: 17988933
    GBP:
        wallet: 17988936
        user: 17988933
    USD:
        wallet: 17988935
        user: 17988933
    PLN:
        wallet: 17988937
        user: 17988933
refund_fee: 0.15
refund_compensation: 0.15
refund_deductions_limit: 0.5
snippets:
    google_analytics: false
    zopim: false
    go_squared: false
    hotjar: false
    facebook: false
    google_tag_manager: false
    google_remarketing: false
    autopilot: false
router.request_context.host: langu2.loc
router.request_context.scheme: http
redis.password: null
redis.port: 6379
liip_imagine_data_path:
    - '%kernel.root_dir%/../web/uploads/'
    - '%kernel.root_dir%/../web/images/'
    - '%kernel.root_dir%/../uploads/'
main_domain: langu2.loc
allowed_mimetypes_lib:
    - text/plain
    - text/richtext
    - application/rtf
    - image/jpg
    - image/jpeg
    - image/png
    - image/gif
    - application/pdf
    - video/avi
    - video/msvideo
    - video/mpeg
    - video/H264
    - video/ogg
    - video/mp4
    - audio/mp4
    - audio/mpeg
    - audio/ogg
    - application/vnd.ms-excel
    - application/msword
    - application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.text
    - application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.spreadsheet
    - application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.presentation
    - application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document
    - application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet
    - application/vnd.ms-powerpoint
    - application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.presentation
max_size_lib: 10485760
```

redis.yml:

```
snc_redis:
clients:
    default:
        type: phpredis
        alias: default
        dsn: redis://localhost
        logging: false
session:
    client: default
    prefix: "session:php:"
```

composer.json:

```
{
"name": "patryk/langu_2",
"license": "proprietary",
"type": "project",
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "": "src/"
    },
    "classmap": [
        "app/AppKernel.php",
        "app/AppCache.php",
        "api/ApiKernel.php",
        "api/ApiCache.php",
        "admin/AdminKernel.php",
        "admin/AdminCache.php"
    ]
},
"require": {
    "php": ">=7.0",
    "symfony/symfony": "2.8.*",
    "doctrine/orm": "^2.4.8",
    "doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "~1.4",
    "symfony/swiftmailer-bundle": "~2.3",
    "symfony/monolog-bundle": "~2.4",
    "sensio/distribution-bundle": "~5.0",
    "sensio/framework-extra-bundle": "^3.0.2",
    "incenteev/composer-parameter-handler": "~2.0",
    "google/apiclient": "^2.1",
    "troopers/mangopay-bundle": "^2.0",
    "pinano/select2-bundle": "^4.0",
    "liip/imagine-bundle": "^1.6",
    "oneup/uploader-bundle": "^1.7",
    "vich/uploader-bundle": "^1.6",
    "ocramius/proxy-manager": "^1.0",
    "nesbot/carbon": "^1.32",
    "twig/extensions": "^1.4",
    "webit/bcmath-bundle": "^1.2",
    "opentok/opentok": "^2.4",
    "debesha/doctrine-hydration-profiler-bundle": "^1.2",
    "willdurand/js-translation-bundle": "^2.6",
    "knplabs/knp-snappy-bundle": "^1.4",
    "h4cc/wkhtmltopdf-amd64": "^0.12.3",
    "cocur/slugify": "^2.3",
    "sonata-project/doctrine-extensions": "^1.0",
    "hampe/zurb-ink-bundle": "^2.2",
    "suncat/mobile-detect-bundle": "^1.0",
    "snc/redis-bundle": "^2.0",
    "doctrine/doctrine-migrations-bundle": "^1.2",
    "stof/doctrine-extensions-bundle": "^1.2",
    "phpunit/phpunit": "^6.3",
    "knplabs/knp-markdown-bundle": "^1.5",
    "sonata-project/admin-bundle": "^3.12",
    "sonata-project/doctrine-orm-admin-bundle": "^3.1",
    "sonata-project/user-bundle": "^3.2",
    "sonata-project/easy-extends-bundle": "^2.1",
    "sonata-project/intl-bundle": "^2.3",
    "sonata-project/translation-bundle": "^2.1",
    "friendsofsymfony/user-bundle": "^1.3",
    "sonata-project/formatter-bundle": "^3.2",
    "helios-ag/fm-elfinder-bundle": "~6",
    "a2lix/translation-form-bundle": "~1.0",
    "pusher/pusher-php-server": "^3.1",
    "league/iso3166": "^2.1",
    "autologic-web/redirect-bundle": "^0.2.2"
},
"require-dev": {
    "sensio/generator-bundle": "~3.0",
    "symfony/phpunit-bridge": "~2.7"
},
"scripts": {
    "symfony-scripts": [
        "Incenteev\\ParameterHandler\\ScriptHandler::buildParameters",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::buildBootstrap"
    ],
    "post-install-cmd": [
        "@symfony-scripts"
    ],
    "post-update-cmd": [
        "@symfony-scripts"
    ]
},
"config": {
    "bin-dir": "bin",
    "component-dir": "web/assets"
},
"extra": {
    "symfony-app-dir": "app",
    "symfony-web-dir": "web",
    "symfony-assets-install": "relative",
    "incenteev-parameters": {
        "file": "app/config/parameters.yml"
    },
    "branch-alias": null
}
```

}

Comment: в php.ini включены `extension=php_igbinary.dll` и `extension=php_redis.dll` ?

Comment: @Dmitry Kozlov спасибо большое это исправило ошибку и кеш очистился, но по прежнему на сайте 500 ошибка

Comment: смотрите логи. попробуйте server:run запустить. Возможно еще чего-то в ini не хватает

Comment: теперь новая ошибка, после `composer update`

Comment: `[Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\ContextErrorException]     
  Warning: Redis::set() expects at least 2 parameters, 0 given ` подскажите как исправить

Comment: это надо в логике копаться. `$redis->set('key', 'value');` требует минимум два параметра ключ и значение. А где метод без параметров вызывается - х.з.

Comment: @DmitryKozlov все заработало, но только на вирт. машине через server:run и ошибок нет, а вот на локале по прежнему 500 ошибка, даже представить не могу почему так

Comment: а в 500-й дает описание ошибки?

Comment: @DmitryKozlov `This page isn’t working langu2.loc is currently unable to handle this request.
HTTP ERROR 500` вот все что пишет

Comment: В /var/log/apache2/langu2_error.log что-нить пишет по этому поводу?

Comment: @DmitryKozlov странно но log пустой

Comment: возможно стоит разрешить отображение ошибок по максимуму в php.ini, можно попробовать перевести проект в dev mode (если проект предусматривает такую возможность)

Comment: @DmitryKozlov вот лог свежий:
`[Fri Oct 19 11:56:41.259427 2018] [php7:error] [pid 24614] [client 127.0.0.1:36474] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught RuntimeException: Unable to create the cache directory (/var/www/langu2.loc/app/cache/prod)\n in /var/www/langu2.loc/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/Kernel.php:591\nStack trace:\n#0 /var/www/langu2.loc/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/Kernel.php(507): Symfony\\Component\\HttpKernel\\Kernel->buildContainer()\n#1

Comment: _Unable to create the cache directory (/var/www/langu2.loc/app/cache/prod)_ не может создать каталог. Смотрите, может прав не хватает или нужной структуры каталогов

Comment: владельца www-data назначил это исправило проблему, теперь новая: `PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Symfony\\Component\\DependencyInjection\\Exception\\ParameterNotFoundException: You have requested a non-existent parameter "max_size_lib"`, этот max_size_lib установлен у меня в parameters.yml `max_size_lib: 10485760` это значение мне надо где-то в php.ini поменять ?

Comment: @DmitryKozlov я нашел решение этой проблемы, выполнив команду `composer run post-install-cmd`